# JAX, pure functions and how to debug it

Tags: jax

I am struggling a bit with debugging non pure, non trivial functions in JAX. Their [documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions) on it is rather simple which is fine when you start learning about it. Conceptually, pure function are rather easy to understand. However, when you start developing some new tools you might get `Leaked tracers` and debugging it is extremely hard.

It would be great to have a tutorial on non trivial examples in JAX with `Leaked tracer errors` and the solution to those examples with their explanation.

Comment: This question is too open-ended to be suitable as a StackOverflow question. Can you edit your question to provide an example of a code snippet whose behavior you are confused about?